# What's a fun troll bughouse opening?

Tags: bughouse

I have been playing e3, Ke2, Kd3 openings in the bughouse chess variation on chess.com.

I got to 1800 pretty easily. I'm looking for other openings to play. As a side note, pushing down a4-a5-a6 is actually pretty strong.

Comment: 1.h4, 2.h5 3.h6. The point is to weaken squares, and it's even better than pushing the a-pawn since it's closer to Black's king.

Answer (score 4):

Sacrificing a piece on f7 (via Nf3-g5-f7 or e4, Bc4, Bxf7) creates a hole on f7 which can later be filled by a parachuting piece. This can be quite effective particularly if you have paratroopers ready from your partner's game.